# What does OE do on TXB0102 device

Tags: level-translation

Can somebody explain in short terms whats means this from datasheet  TXB0102:

> When the output-enable (OE) input is low, all outputs are placed in
>   the high-impedance state.

I dont know how I would connect the OE pin

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> When the output-enable (OE) input is low, all outputs are placed in
>   the high-impedance state.

This means that if you make OE low (connect it to GND) then all outputs are switched off. The chip will **do nothing** in this state. Basically it is like the chip has been removed from the circuit (I know that's not 100% accurate but it is a simple analogy).

If you make OE high (connect it to VCCA, so 1.8 V in your design) then the chip's output are enabled and everything is working.

Comment: Thanks very much, now I have more clear the circuit

Answer (score 0):

From the website:

> When the output-enable (OE) input is low, all outputs are placed in
>   the high-impedance state.

This means that if you don't need to switch the TXB0102 device from a high impedance state to a normally operating state, then pull the OE pin high. You could do that with a 20k pull up resistor.

If you do need to switch the state, connect it to a microprocessor pin or digital logic.

You could use the TXB0102 OE pin to switch it into a high impedance state to create buffers on a bus.

Comment: Thanks... I am only trying connect 1v8 serial tx/rx of sim7600 to ATMega 2560 MCU serial 5V. I will connect to 1v8 with a pull up resistor :)
If I want to connect directly to a digital pin of mcu I should use resistor from TX to RX and RX to TX ?

Comment: If you are using ports with high impedance (they sink uA's) then you don't need a  current limiting resistor. If the ports can sink mA, then you need a current limiting resistor. The TXB0102 can source up to 50mA (but will kill the device if you sink more than 50mA). Find the current sink of the load that you are connecting the output port of the TXB0102, then find VoH and calculate the current. Current can affect switching speeds. Usually a few hundered ohm resistor is appropriate, like a 100 ohm resistor.

Comment: SIM7600 High-level output voltage 1.8V máx High-level output current(no
pull down resistor) 2mA typ ATmega2560 VOH 5V 20mA